# PHP variable is not accessible in HTML template

Tags: php, html, function, templates, variables

**index.php**

```
<?php 
$title = "World";
echo loadTemplate();
?>
```

**Template.php**

```
<?php
function loadTemplate(){
    return <<<EOF
    Hello {$title}
    EOF;
}
?>
```

On running **index.php** it should output `Hello World` but its only printing `Hello`. How can I make my script echo `Hello World`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [globals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

> This script will not produce any output because the heredoc refers to a local version of the `$title` variable, and it has not been assigned a value within this scope.

You need to tell PHP you want to use `$title` as a global.

```
function loadTemplate(){
    global $title;
    return <<<EOF
    Hello {$title}
    EOF;
}
```

or, and this is preferable as globals are messy, pass it as an argument:

```
function loadTemplate($what){
    global $title;
    return <<<EOF
    Hello {$what}
    EOF;
}

echo loadTemplate($title);
```

Comment: any better idea to do that without global and passing parameters

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to go full OO, define a class and store the value as a property of the instance of the class. That probably isn't "better" unless this is a very heavily simplified example. It's also very hard to determine what might be better if you are rejecting the use of arguments (which is the standard way to do this sort of thing in practically every programming language).

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you want to use a global variable inside a function you need to declare it, using the `global` keyword to bring it into scope :

```
function loadTemplate() {
  global $title;
  return <<<EOF
    Hello {$title}
    EOF;
}
```

Comment: any better idea to do that without global and passing parameters

Comment: I doubt there's another way around that

Answer (score 0):

It's quite sloppy and bad practice using `global`s. It shows a lazy developer and when you come back to it a while later you wont know what `$title` was.

```
$title = "World";
echo loadTemplate($title);

function load_template($title)
{
    return <<<EOF
Hello, {$title}
EOF;
}
```

For more information you should look into the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Note: your original code is incorrect, the closing identifier, `EOF` in your case, cannot be indented.